# zsh, expand * to (a|b|c)

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Say I have a directory with files

```
a  b  c
```

If I type

```
> ls *
```

and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>, zsh changes it to

```
> ls a b c
```

Is there a way to have it instead change to

```
> ls (a|b|c)
```

?

Comment: I do not believe that this is possible or rather it is not just a setting in *zsh* and you would have to write your own completion function to replace the default file completion.What would be the use case for this? Maybe there is another solution aside from utilizing the completion system.